# When I try to move my selenium code to a java dynamic web project it gives me error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver

Tags: eclipse, jsp, selenium-webdriver

When I try to move my selenium code to a java dynamic web project it gives me error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver`

I have eclispe Juno installed. Please note that I am not suing Maven.
configured Apache tomcat 7
and created a simple Dynamic Web Project with one jsp file with a `<form>` with a simple Submit button `<input type="submit">`. Ran the project the web page is displayed correctly.
Then updated the jsp file form action as `<form action="test">`
In the *test.java* servlet file added a line selenium line as

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

And then ran the project again, but got error as below

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:892)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5416)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
```

I ensured that Selenium Jar is added in the Web App Libraries and the jar is displayed under `WEB-INF/lib/selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar`. But still this error is coming. Is there something that I am missing here. Any clue/help greatly appreciated.

I tried adding other jars like mysql, log4j inside dynamic web project and wrote codes that uses these jars and there is no problem . Only selenium is giving this issue. 
Is it not possible to use selenium codes in dynamic web project?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find a solution for this by following the help from this link
http://me-ol-blog.blogspot.in/2013/07/using-selenium-in-java-dynamic-web.html

First Removed my Selenium jar from `WEB-INF/lib` in my Dynamic Web Project. Then
 is what I did based on the instruction provided in the above link:

1. Unzipped the Selenium jar, in my case i used `selenium-java-2.46.0`
2. The unzipped folder contains `selenium-java-2.46.0.jar` and `lib` folder
3. Copy the `selenium-java-2.46.0.jar`into  `WEB-INF/lib`
4. Copy all the jars under `lib` folder into  `WEB-INF/lib` And ensure that these added jars are displayed under the Web App libraries
5. Restarted my Tomcat server and ran my code. It worked like charm.

And yes, as tim-slifer rightly pointed out, we should use the selenium-java jar and not the standalone server jar.
Also, i guess, if MAVEN is used i wont have these issues.

`

Comment: My bad, there was a typo at the end of the URL. Updated it correctly. It should work now.

Comment: Okay But you need to take care in future. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've never used selenium inside a dynamic web project, but I'm pretty sure your problem is using the selenium-server-standalone jar as the dependency.  Selenium-server-standalone starts a Selenium Grid instance, which is not the same as the framework itself.  Instead, grab the java language binding (selenium-java.jar) as your dependency.

A quick note... I'm sure you may have reasons for not using Maven, but it might help with your dependency management.  You otherwise may be in for some work tracking down all the transitive dependencies of the Selenium framework.

Comment: Hi tim-slifer, thanks for your inputs. And I agree that Maven is one among the best approaches to maintain dependency. Also I have workaround the issue and will be posting the answer to my problem shortly.